# How to remove conflict between click event and programmatically triggered click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I am trying to remove ul element on click of body element and ignore if the click target is on the ul element itself otherwise click execute and ul get removed.
Every thing works well but a programmatic click from another js removes ul after its execution which is a problem.The ul should be removed by the user interaction only. Please help me to solve this conflict.

```
<div class="search-input">
     <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).on('click','body', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).closest(".search-input").find('ul').length > 0) {
        $('.search-input ul').remove();
    }   
});
```

// programmatic click trigger
`$(hotspot).trigger("click", true);`

The above programmatic click event execute the body click event which is not required.

Comment: Why're you having duplicate if and remove?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: give full working example

Comment: I have added the ul element above and want it to get removed when user manually trigger click and not by the programmatic click event

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition.

```
is_click  = true;
$(document).on('click','body', function(e) {
if(is_click){
    if(!$(e.target).closest(".search-input").find('ul').length > 0) {
        $('.search-input ul').remove();
    }

    if(!$(e.target).closest(".input-search").find('ul').length > 0) {
        $('.input-search ul').remove();
    } 
}  
});
```

and for programmatic click trigger

```
is_click  = false;
$(hotspot).trigger("click", true);
is_click  = true;
```